# Delete query didn't work properly

Tags: java, sql

DELETE query didn't work properly, the row deleted from the JTable but it still available in the database, and when I refresh the JTable it return available again inside it.

```
  DefaultTableModel m=(DefaultTableModel)tbl.getModel();
    if (tbl.getSelectedRow()==-1){
        if(tbl.getRowCount()==0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table is Empty");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Must Select a Row");
        }
    else{
        int rowIndex = tbl.getSelectedRow();

        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to permanently delete "
                + MainFrame.pArray.get(rowIndex).name+" information ?","Delete Record",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

     String id = MainFrame.pArray.get(rowIndex).id;

        String sql = "delete from patient where id =?";
    try {
        connect();
        if( conn != null){
        PreparedStatement sttmnt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        sttmnt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));
        sttmnt.executeUpdate();
        m.removeRow(tbl.getSelectedRow());
        MainFrame.pArray.remove(rowIndex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
        conn.close();
        }
    }       catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to commit the transaction before closing the connection. Do this instead:

`conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`